# Getting startURL nullified on Customized Change Password page to login

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, customer-portal, login, change-password

I am using Custom Change Password page (built on VF) for Force.com site. The same page we are using for 3 different layouts - mobile, web and app view. For the app, I have put a logic that redirects to new change password page that's specific only to the mobile app. After setting the password, I want a user to login directly to the system using `site.login(username, password, startURL)`, but startURL is null on this page as we are losing the context of this value. 
I was able to generate startURL on Sign In as below-

```
String startURL = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
```

But the same doesn't seem to work on a new Change Password page. Any suggestions to counter this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it.
I captured the current page context at Custom Change Password page as below -

```
window.location.href = '{!$Page.ChangePasswordPage}?startUrl={!URLENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.retURL)}';
```

Retrieved it at customized change password page as below -

`startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');`

And to log in, using below script -

```
Site.login(username, newPassword, startUrl);
```